# Modify existing object in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have some problem with my ASP.NET MVC application. How can I modify an existing object created previously in different `ActionResult`?

I created object in this action:

```
public ActionResult getLogin(AccountViewModel accountViewModel)
{
    Account account2 = de.Accounts.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Username == accountViewModel.Account.Username);
    PasswordReminder.PasswordReminder reminder = new PasswordReminder.PasswordReminder();
    reminder.showQuestion(account2.Username);
    return View("Question", reminder);
}
```

And I want to add an attribute to the existing reminder object by this ActionResult

```
@model PasswordReminder.PasswordReminder
@{
Layout = null;
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Question</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
 @Model.questionReminder 
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Answer", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.reminderAnswer)
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    }
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So in my View "Answer" in attribute "reminderAnswer" I entered value but questionReminder is null, so this must be a new object..  Thanks for all help

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, in order to achieve what you are after, the PasswordReminder object that you are using as your Model, must be persisted in the getLogin action, and then passed back separately as the model from your action that feeds your Answer view (but I recommend to use a ViewModel as an abstraction over the previous PasswordReminder object for security)

This would insure you are referencing the previously instantiated PasswordReminder object in your Answer view, in order to modify the value of reminderAnswer property.